# creating many dynamic links with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, generics, dynamic

have a static links which is feeded with data from js function.

```
<div class="link">
     <a id="pdfdocument" class="button" target="_blank" href="#">Download starten</a>
     <a id="xlsdocument" class="button" target="_blank" href="#">Download starten</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
if (contentElement.name.indexOf(".xls") != -1) {
    "<a id='" + $("#xlsdocument").attr("href", "/dcontent?element=" + contentElement.id + "&handle=" + openBi.handle) + "</a>";
    $('#pubExcel').html(contentElement.filename);
} else {
    $("#pdfdocument").attr("href", "/dcontent?element=" + contentElement.id + "&handle=" + openBi.handle);
    $('#pubPdf').html(contentElement.filename);
}
```

my question is, how to create generic link if i have loaded more than one document. for example 4 documents = 4 links for pdf and 4 excel in html, 40 documents = 40 links for pdf and 40 excel in html..
struggeling on such a easy step

Comment: What does that 'contentElement' object contain? Your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: I'm already not following your second line. "Take a string (`<a id='`), add the result of changing the href of #xlsdocument, add another string, and then throw it away."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of all files

```
var documents = ['file_one', 'file_two', 'file_three'];
```

Maybe this would help you:

HTML:

```
<div id="empty_div">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var documents = ['file_one', 'file_two', 'file_three'];

var tmpDocument, tmpAnchorTagPdf, tmpAnchorTagXls, parentContainer, i;

parentContainer = document.getElementById('empty_div');

for (i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
    tmpDocument = documents[i];

    tmpAnchorTagPdf = document.createElement('a');
    tmpAnchorTagPdf.href = 'your-domain.com/' + tmpDocument + '.pdf';
    tmpAnchorTagPdf.innerHTML = 'Start download ' + tmpDocument + '.pdf';

    tmpAnchorTagXls = document.createElement('a');
    tmpAnchorTagXls.href = 'your-domain.com/' + tmpDocument + '.xls';
    tmpAnchorTagXls.innerHTML = 'Start download ' + tmpDocument + '.xls';

    parentContainer.appendChild(tmpAnchorTagPdf);
    parentContainer.appendChild(tmpAnchorTagXls);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6Dy5/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of other questions but the below is how you create a dynamic link:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "href here";
// append it where you want
```